# MonoTouch: Localization from a Common Project

Tags: c#, ios, localization, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have created a Common Library MonoTouch project and added the localization files there. However, they do not appear in the .app file.

How can I have a common project with localization resources so that I can share them among many MonoTouch apps?

As a side: I can add Images to a common project and access them so I am assuming it'll work with Localization files. Localization works fine when the localization files are in the main app project.

[image: The project containing the Localization files]

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue! https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Common.Localization.csproj needs to have at least 1 class in it to make it compile to a DLL. That class needs to be referenced in the main app too.

Just create a Dummie class.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace Common.Localization
{
[Preserve]
public class DummieClassNeededToMakeLocalizationCompileToaDLL
{
    [Preserve]
    public DummieClassNeededToMakeLocalizationCompileToaDLL ()
    {
    }
}
}
```